# What scope (conn, db, scheme) does have database transaction?

Tags: database, postgresql, transactions

I want to know what scope does the database transaction have.

If the transaction is created, can I access the transaction from another:

1. connection?
2. database?
3. scheme?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you understand transactions in RDBMS. You can create transaction inside the session and then you can COMMIT or ROLLBACK the transaction. There is no option for sharing transaction between connections, databases and schemas. You can read more about transactions here: [PostgreSQL transactions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-transactions.html)

There is an option create a two-phase commit transaction. If you create this type of transaction, the transaction is no more connected to the session and the state is stored on disk. But I think this is not what you mean. You can read more about [two-phase commit transactions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare-transaction.html).